# Video.js incompatible with mp4 video

Tags: video.js

My code does not work with the phone recorded videos ( MP4 ) .

Have tested other videos mp4 and it works normally.

Does he not support the video phone ?

```
Video Features :

Format : MPEG - 4
Format profile: Base Media
Codec ID : isom
File size: 29.8 MiB
Duration : 21mn 2s
Overall bit rate: 198 Kbps
Writing application : Lavf52.84.0

Video
ID: 1
Format : MPEG - 4 Visual
Format profile: Simple @ L1
Format settings , BVOP : No
Format settings , QPEL On
Format settings , GMC : No warppoints
Format settings , Matrix : Default ( H.263 )
Codec ID: 20
Duration : 21mn 2s
Bit rate: 97.5 Kbps
Width : 176 pixels
Height : 144 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 1.222
Frame rate mode: Constant
Frame rate: 29.970 fps
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type: Progressive
Compression mode: Lossy
Bits / ( Pixel * Frame) : 0.128
Stream size: 14.7 MiB ( 49 % )
Writing library : Lavc52.97.0

audio
ID: 2
Format : MPEG Audio
Format version: Version 1
Format profile: Layer 3
Mode: Joint stereo
Mode extension: MS Stereo
Codec ID: 6B
Duration : 21mn 2s
Bit rate mode: Constant
Bit rate: 96.0 Kbps
Channel ( s ) : 2 channels
Sampling rate: 44.1 KHz
Compression mode: Lossy
Stream size: 14.4 MiB ( 48 % )
Writing library : LAME3.98.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your video format is MPEG-4 Visual, which chrome doesn't support.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54036

It's confusing, but that's not the same as a more standard MP4 file which uses the h.264 codec. Your info should look something like this:

```
General
Complete name                            : filename.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
...

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
...
```

Try using something like [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr) or [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com) to transcode the video.